# Android Studion Dependency resolving hangs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to learn building android apps, but I have ran into the following problem.
After I create a new project, the **Gradle** build starts and it is hanging at the following process.

[image]

I am inclined to believe that the connection that I use blocks several ports and it is impossible for the studio to download the necessary file.
Knowing this, I downloaded **gradle** from their homepage, and I've set the local path in android to that folder, but there is no change.
This is what I get after the gradle build times out.

[image]

What can I do to bypass my connection settings and build a proper project?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy?

Comment: I am. That's the main problem.

Comment: Is there a way to download the necessary files and add them in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough traffic,you can open you mobile hotspot ,then computer connect to the wifi.So,create a project and Gradle,have a try!The junit package isn't very big.Hope can help you.

Comment: At first, I also had this kind of situation,my network‘s bandwidth is 50M,but also can't gradle successfully.Then I used the mobile's wifi,it's ok.

Comment: The current pc that I am using has setup a network security key if I want to connect to the other wi-fi connection. I cannot bypass that.

Comment: in build.gradle: allprojects{

repositories{

jcenter()

}

},modify jcenter() as mavenCental(),then have a try

Comment: Now what I get is 
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
   > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     Required by:
         App:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
               > Connect to repo1.maven.org:443 [repo1.maven.org/151.101.44.209] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: So my connection times out everytime.